# How can one set multiple authorization headers in axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
const http = axios.create();
http.interceptors.request.use(
  async function(config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.headers.common.Authorization = "87930232548793023254";
    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

As I've added one header - config.headers.common.Authorization. How can I add another one authorization header to the same instance?

Comment: Two `Authorization` headers in a HTTP request is not something you want to do. What do you want to accomplish? You might be able to add two values to the same header though, e.g. `Authorization: 87930232548793023254, 1234566789`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add multiple headers with same name. However, you could assign the values to different names as follows:

```
config.headers.common.Authorization = '87930232548793023254';
config.headers.common.Authorization2 = '1112233445567788994';
```